# Unusual error in code igniter system file when deployed to a VPS server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently finished building my site using code igniter on WAMP local server and tested it on a shared hosting server (from Namecheap). Then I got VPS hosting plan (from iPage) and uploaded the files and did the necessary configs. However, I got this error when I tried accessing the site:

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function ctype_digit()

Filename: /home/eastngco/public_html/system/core/Security.php

Line Number: 600

Problem is, the suspect file, Security.php, is a code igniter system file which I never messed with (everything I wrote was within the application folder). Below is a code snippet around the line in Security.php causing the error:

```
/**
 * Get random bytes
 *
 * @param   int $length Output length
 * @return  string
 */
public function get_random_bytes($length)
{
    if (empty($length) OR ! ctype_digit((string) $length))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (function_exists('random_bytes'))
    {
        try
        {
            // The cast is required to avoid TypeError
            return random_bytes((int) $length);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // If random_bytes() can't do the job, we can't either ...
            // There's no point in using fallbacks.
            log_message('error', $e->getMessage());
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Unfortunately, none of the following PRNGs is guaranteed to exist ...
    if (defined('MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM') && ($output = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)) !== FALSE)
    {
        return $output;
    }


    if (is_readable('/dev/urandom') && ($fp = fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')) !== FALSE)
    {
        // Try not to waste entropy ...
        is_php('5.4') && stream_set_chunk_size($fp, $length);
        $output = fread($fp, $length);
        fclose($fp);
        if ($output !== FALSE)
        {
            return $output;
        }
    }

    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes'))
    {
        return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I have no idea what random bytes or ctype_digit() means!

I did some digging on the web to see if a similar problem (and its solution) would pop, but nothing did. I need help fixing this please.
If it means anything, the PHP version that comes with my hosting plan is version 7, and I have SSL.

Comment: I thought the point of a VPS is that you are in control of the server? You probably need to enable ctype functions and restart apache.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but i really don't know how to do that. This is my first time using a VPS

Comment: What operating system? What version of the operating system? Is the webserver Apache or nginx? Do you have command line access as root?

Comment: sorry i could not reply earlier. I contacted my web host and had ctype enabled, but the problem still persists.

Comment: OS is CentOS 6.4 x86_64. Apache webserver.

Comment: VTC as typo/not reproducible per comment on answer "well, i later figured out the source of d bug. It had nothing to do with the fingered file, but my .htaccess file"

Answer (score 1):

Ipage has a support page to enable the ctype extension, please read this article, using code igniter and PHP: 7.4.10, I receive this error message: Call to undefined function ctype_digit().
Enabling this extension in Ipage the problem was solved in my case.
Article:
https://www.ipage.com/help/article/how-to-enable-ctype-so-extensions-in-php-ini

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your provider might have explicitly disabled those types of functions. It *should* be enabled by default. Try contacting your provider for some support on enabling these, or reinstalling PHP without that flag turned off.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ctype.installation.php

Additionally, you could try and inspect a `phpinfo()` page to confirm whether ctypes are enabled or not. It seems weird that they would turn it off, so this would help figure out if this is part of the issue.

Comment: I have contacted my web host and they enabled ctype for me, but problem still persists

Comment: well, i later figured out the source of d bug. It had nothing to do with the fingered file, but my .htaccess file